# ASP.Net Positioning of controls

Tags: asp.net

I have created this web form using absolute positioning instead of relative. As expected controls are not displayed properly on other computers/browsers. I need to correct this without changing the layout of controls. Is there a way out or do I need to rebuild my webpage

Comment: It's a difficult question to answer without knowing the structure of the HTML page.

Comment: Or knowing how the controls are 'not displayed properly', that's a statement that could be hiding a multitude of sins.

Comment: I am using a css style sheet and controls move out of display area

Comment: Can I use <ASP:Table> control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to overcome this without tampering all the existing HTML markup will be to enclose all the HTML inside a parent element either positioned absolutely or relatively to the window.

```
<style>
   #divOuter { position: relative; }
</style>
<div id='divOuter'>
<!--all your HTML markup goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of parent element? Can you suggest something

Comment: Use a div as the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

All controls on the page dont need to be asp.net controls, you can still use regular old HTML wherever you want.